# Better way to use Laravel login into a "legacy system"?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, migrating

I need to make a migration of a legacy system to Laravel.
I'm using PHP 5.6 and we have a login system using session and cookies to personalize some user stuffs.
Well, I want to migrate some parts of my system and the first one I believe that will be Login, I think that I need to share login between Laravel and the old PHP, but what is the better way to do it? The users password wasn't into bcrypt encryption and I will need to share the "login" into old system pages, and the new pages migrated to Laravel..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new ServiceProvider such as `LegacyHashProvider`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\LegacyHasher;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LegacyHashProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('hash', function ($app) {
            return new LegacyHasher($app);
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['hash'];
    }
}
```

Create a class `LegacyHasher` which implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher` interface. Write down your methods(override) such as;

```
public function make($value, array $options = [])
{
    return hash('sha512', $value); // this will be your legacy hashing system 
}
```

Navigate to config/app.php and replace `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class` with `App\Providers\LegacyHashProvider` and it should be ready to use your legacy login system.

Comment: So, how can I share that "login",  example: I have a search products page in a legacy side, but when my client click in one product, they send to a product page in Laravel side, in both page that guy needs to be logged, how can I share it?

Comment: @Hermus Let's say you use a remote and shared session database to keep track of user interactions between two systems. When user is logged-in from any of the sides you put key/value pairs such as `user:some-hashed-session-value-for-user-1:new` or `user:some-hashed-session-value-for-user-1:legacy`. Laravel side will be covered both `authenticate` middleware and checking the existence of legacy key - legacy system will check the existence of both keys. Whenever a user logs-out from either side you delete both of the keys. It will be like using a single gmail account for multiple google services.

Comment: @Hermus there are many details to cover all the scenarios but that's the concept. You keep those long some hashed session value in user's session in both of the applications and make a request with them as identifier.